# How to make changes in xdg-user-dirs.dirs have effect in files lens?

Tags: unity, 11.10, files, lenses, xdg

I've changed some favourite folder locations in `~/.config/xdg-user-dirs.dirs`, since I prefer different locations for `Music` and `Pictures` folder, and nautilus recognized the changes. However the Unity files lens don't. If I try to open e.g. music folder from files lens, Unity tries to open the old folder location.

How to make changes in `~/.config/xdg-user-dirs.dirs` have effect in files lens?

Thanks

Comment: Very simple solution.

Unity files lens uses bookmarks from nautilus. After editing _~/.config/xdg-user-dirs.dirs_ the bookmarks are invalid, so I edited them with the bookmark editor in nautilus and now everything works well.

Answer (score 1):

I've modified paths in  ~/.config/xdg-user-dirs.dirs and music lens finds songs w/o problems.
have you tried to open banshee, update collection with the new path and look back at the lens?

Comment: Banshee uses the correct location for my music, but files lens don't find any music files. I updated the collection, no effect.